# Is it possible to declare dynamic string type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Suppose:

```js
export enum EEnv { devint, qa1 };
export type TEnv = keyof typeof EEnv;
export const env:Record<TEnv, {something:number}> = {
  devint: {
    something: 1,
  },
  qa1: {
    something: 1,
  },
}
```

Then I want to create dynamic object based on `env` object, like this:

```js
export const SAVE_TOKEN: Record<TEnv, string> = {
  devint: "SAVE_TOKEN/devint", // based on "env" key
  qa1: "SAVE_TOKEN/qa1", // based on "env" key
}
```

Is there any way to create type of string to be ***`"SAVE_TOKEN/"+TEnv`*** rather that just string.

Comment: If you're using a framework like angular, this is built in. If you're not, check out https://webpack.js.org/.  Tutorial on a basic example using environment variables: https://medium.com/@justintulk/passing-environment-variables-into-your-code-with-webpack-cab09d8974b0

Answer (score 7):

Update for those who still find their way here: this will be added in 4.1, see [TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336).

```js
export type SaveTokenNamespace<K extends string> = { [T in K]: `SAVE_TOKEN/${T}` };

export function makeNamespace<K extends TEnv>(env: Record<K, unknown>): SaveTokenNamespace<K> {
  return Object.keys(env).reduce((ns, k) => ({ ...ns, [k]: `SAVE_TOKEN/${k}` }), {} as SaveTokenNamespace<K>);
}

console.log(makeNamespace(env));
const envNamespace = makeNamespace(env);
const test1: 'SAVE_TOKEN/qa1' = envNamespace.qa1; // Ok!
const test2: 'SAVE_TOKEN/notqa1' = envNamespace.qa1; // Error: Type '"SAVE_TOKEN/qa1"' is not assignable to type '"SAVE_TOKEN/notqa1"'.
```

[Try it in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&module=0&ts=4.1.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKIcQNzgbzgBNgcBLRGAGjgEcBDARjgF8BuAWAChRJY4YATzDA4AFWx4AvHADWwQRABmA4cGWZJnHuGjwAxhEQBneEhwAuOACVghqEQA8E3DULGIqYDAAWFAOZWKKgARsBQrAB8cDL43HDEpBQwVnFcCQkeXr4BVoxU8awF6XRMqYWZnt5+iIFw+YUsxezc3Lx6qiJwAMr0OMBiEPKIAHL0XsZg9PrAjgDSCCAwSETGcKZQAdGxcADaYnAUcHMAulYABt0AggBqGAD6YgDycxgjAPQAJPhiLOes2jaun4SmQiH0MDIRjgqHo8jGEymM3mi2WiFW4kkkQAFOYrLZ7E45jQwbJEBAAO6ISIASisvX6g2GCOAk2mszm0TSCSg3mQUEQcCeIQAVnYYAA6eSCYy43A0iW8ojIGbY7EmGiyGkxaLYwgSg0avayM5wS63B7PV4fb6yP6sGluFhwehrBkDIZIFls5GcmnaFitLiGEwQAA2wAlYYg-mxsPh41ZSOAcpwNP93BDpgQuG9yZiMLhwDz7NTGeDRmzy1MjCsAHJrndHi83u8GIw6wXzCWZhL22w4O93kLZABCTOV+DVmAAJnrjctLY+5Jg7c7Mm7iZ9kf7g+HGCgUGgVjEajgdYARAvm9a20wL52yGsVy7jMYyP5EPQQhGBBBOqIl7XlarYru2D4SkAA)

---

There are some popular open proposals/requests including [Regex-validated string type: TypeScript#6579](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) and [TypeScript#12754](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) with a [comment about this exact use case](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754#issuecomment-351066369), but as of 3.5.1 the answer is no.